# Outlook graph API : Want to call API on receiving email on an email

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I want to do some automation like calling my API on receiving email on some email. I checked that its possible using microsoft graph API. But did not find particularly which in graph API.

Would appreciate if anyone can share their experience about this or share me the API.